# Explaining the Meaning of the G#6b5 Piano Chord played in the Key of C Major

Tags: chord-theory

How does one explaining the meaning of the G#6b5 Chord to another with little to no musical background of Chords?

Comment: Can you give an example of something that you _do_ understand? Understanding chord patterns means that you can either (1) accept the concept or pattern as an atomic law-of-nature type of thing that you can use and recognize as such, or (2) see the concept or pattern in terms of other simpler and more familiar concepts and patterns from category 1. In this question you're asking for an explanation that would go to category 2, and in order to give such an explanation we need to know what there might be in your set of category 1 concepts or patterns.

Comment: That chord doesn't really exist - or need to exist  - in key C.

Comment: Welcome. Is this what you're asking?,'I have no real understanding of chords. What does G#6b5 mean?'

Comment: The function of a chord depends entirely on the context-- the chords before and the chords after, the rhythmic position (down beat or upbeat), how the notes of the chord are resolved, and the harmonic language invoked by the piece overall. Can you edit your post and provide any of that information?

Comment: Downvoted because I can't think of any usage of that chord fitting those qualifications (spelled that way), and it's hard to tell exactly what question is being asked or what you want answers to address.

Comment: Is that (G#)6(b5) or G(#6)(b5)?

Comment: @It'sHEDLEY Normally it's the first interpretation, you don't need brackets for natural 6. Though I'd agree the symbol is not usual, so some clarification would help.

Comment: Posting a snippet of the actual music would clarify much

Answer (score 8):

First, you find an reasonable name for the set of notes.

This gives you the notes G#, B#, D, E#.

Now respell them as something that looks as if it might be related to C major: Ab, C, D, F.

So this is either an F minor 6 chord, or D half diminished seventh.

If you can't "explain the meaning" of either of those in C major, you need to learn what a II-V-I chord progression is.